# Maximum frequency of digital signal in Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, frequency

As Arduino Uno has a 16 MHz oscillator but while running program it has less frequency because some of the processing power is used for running the program.
I have used the `delay(1)` but it is giving me around 500 Hz.

**My questions:**

1. Is there any way to achieve more than 500 Hz?
2. What would be the maximum frequency of digital signal for below program?

```cpp
void setup() {
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);          
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);         
}
```

Comment: note that digitalWrite is relatively slow. Also, wrapping everything inside a `while(true){...}` will make it a bit faster, instead of letting the loop function exit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Yes, use the hardware timers.
2. You can achieve 8 MHz.

Example sketch which outputs 8 MHz on pin 9 on a Uno:

```C++
#ifdef __AVR_ATmega2560__
  const byte CLOCKOUT = 11;  // Mega 2560
#else
  const byte CLOCKOUT = 9;   // Uno, Duemilanove, etc.
#endif

void setup ()
  {
  // set up 8 MHz timer on CLOCKOUT (OC1A)
  pinMode (CLOCKOUT, OUTPUT); 
  // set up Timer 1
  TCCR1A = bit (COM1A0);  // toggle OC1A on Compare Match
  TCCR1B = bit (WGM12) | bit (CS10);   // CTC, no prescaling
  OCR1A =  0;       // output every cycle
  }  // end of setup

void loop ()
  {
  // whatever 
  }  // end of loop
```

If you change OCR1A you can get lower frequencies. If you change the prescaler you can get lower frequencies again.

See [my page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) for more details.

Comment: Below I have put a oscilloscope waveform from your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Also, don't forget that there are alternative methods of toggling outputs.

You can use PORTS to do the job.

Here's a good [example](http://www.billporter.info/2010/08/18/ready-set-oscillate-the-fastest-way-to-change-arduino-pins/). And another [here](http://tronixstuff.com/2011/10/22/tutorial-arduino-port-manipulation/).

And this code is the idea behind it:

```
void setup()
{
  DDRD = B11111111; // set PORTD (digital 7~0) to outputs
}

void loop()
{
  PORTD = B11111111; // set PORTD pins (digital 7~0) high
  PORTD = B00000000; // set PORTD pins (digital 7~0) low
}
```

P.S. Don't forget that the port numbering is in reference to the chip pins and not the Arduino pins/legs.

Answer (score 2):

**Nick Gammon's** code worked fine for me. Here is an **oscilloscope picture** of the waveform I've got from **his code**:

[image: Output of Arduino UNO pin 9, approximately 1 V peak-to-peak Amplitude with spikes]

His code above (*from Nick Gammon, on Jan 25 '16 at 20:33*) worked excellent for me. I used his code on Arduino UNO and got about **7.9 MHz** of output frequency on an approximately **1 V amplitude** (peak-to-peak, with spikes making it go to about **2 V peak-to-peak amplitude**).

The image above was obtained with my 40 MHz Oscilloscope from *ICEL Manaus* (manufacturer) at pin 9 (I used the Arduino UNO), with a LED and a resistor as a load at pin 9:

- a green LED of about 1.79 V voltage drop
- and a 4.7 Ohms resistor with 5% tolerance

The oscilloscope probe (*Channel 2, with fall slope trigger detect*) is on the 4.7 Ohms resistor. It follows the connection order out of the pin 9 from Arduino UNO:
*PIN 9* > *green LED* > *4.7 Ohms resistor* >  *GROUND*.

The green LED keeps blinking at a normal luminescence, as compared when used at other output frequencies.

I used a external 5 V DC power supply, along with the USB connection on my PC.

If you have any questions just put them here. Thanks and thanks [Nick Gammon](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/users/10794/nick-gammon)

Comment: Glad it worked for you! The slight discrepancy in frequency could be explained by the fact that the Uno has a resonator rather than a crystal as a frequency source for the main processor.